# PHP function with an infinite loop if I use" while" or task not fully achieved if I use "IF" instead of "while"

Tags: php

I have created a function to allocate all the invoices that match some conditions (no user previously allocated and the invoice has a certain status).

The issue is that I can't make the function to run in a loop until the above conditions are false.

If I use `while` in my function, it will create an infinite loop.
If I use `break` at the end of the "while" or amend the while to "if", the function will run only once even though the conditions are still true.

```
$sql_activ_users = "SELECT User FROM Users WHERE STATUS='active' AND User !='X' ORDER by U_ID ASC";
$result_activ_users = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_activ_users);
$activ_users = mysqli_num_rows($result_activ_users);

function userallocation ($conn,$FI_toAllocate,$TP_toAllocate,$MM_Srv_toAllocate,$MM_Mat_toAllocate,$CCG_toAllocate,$result_activ_users) {

$checksql="SELECT COUNT(1) - COUNT(CpProcessor) AS NUMBER 
           FROM TGSB_DB 
           where Workflow like '%Qsent | Sensitive data modification%' 
           or Workflow like '%Qdeclined%' 
           or Workflow like '%QAccepted | Sensitive data modification%' 
           or Workflow like '%QCalled back%' 
           or Workflow like '%Qin process | Sensitive data modification%' 
           or Workflow like '%Qis due | Sensitive data modification%' 
           or Workflow ='' or Workflow is null";
$checkresult = mysqli_query($conn, $checksql);
$nullcount=mysqli_fetch_array($checkresult);
$cnt=(int)$nullcount[0];

while($cnt > 0){

foreach($result_activ_users as $k => $value){
...sql query to update...
}//foreach end
}//while end
}//end of function userallocation ()
```

I expect the function to be executed as long as `$cnt > 0` but the function currently stops after the first run (if I use `if($cnt > 0)` or enters in an infinite loop if I use `while($cnt > 0)`.

Comment: Do you know, how many records must be updated at the beginning? If yes, you can get the records and update them without necessity to check count during every loop iteration.

Comment: Just use a `for` loop: `for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {` instead of a `while` loop

Comment: Where do you modify `$cnt` to not enter an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a decrementing operator to your `$cnt` inside your while loop in order to stop infinite looping.

```
while($cnt > 0){
   foreach($result_activ_users as $k => $value){
      ...sql query to update...
   }//foreach end
  --$cnt; //pre-decrement
}//while end
```